# How many times has the sun orbited the galaxy?

Tags: cosmology, milky-way

Even if our solar system is not in a stable orbit around the center of the galaxy (is it?), since the birth of our sun, how far has it traveled relative to the center of the galaxy?

Comment: Have you used [Wolfram Alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=age+of+the+sun+%2F+orbital+period+of+the+sun) before? It is useful for these types of queries. If you're looking for greater detail, I suggest editing to clarify.

Comment: See also: http://www.universetoday.com/18028/sun-orbit/